# bin folder is missing in Qt installation Path 5.8.0

Tags: visual-studio, qt

During the installation of Qt 5.8.0, I get the following error message:

[image: qmake.exe error message]

If I am reinstalling it as an admin, the error does not appear. But the bin folder is still not existing in the installation path.

Without the bin folder (and the binary) I cannot bind it to Visual Studio. There this error message appears:

[image: No qmake.exe to generate binary]

I have searched a little bit, but did not find a good workaround. Here they say, that I have to change the compatilibity. That does not work:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/1637/cant-install-the-latest-sdk-qmake-exe-being-used-by-another-process

Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding your first error message, `qmake` is being used by any other process?

Comment: I can exclude this - I have checked it with a process explorer, it is not used.

Comment: I have tested it on 3 different machines, everywhere the same result - the bin folder with the binary is missing

Comment: Oh, right! Then, maybe the installer you are using has this issue. Did you try to download it again and compare with the existing one?

Comment: I have downloaded it twice, and used both Visual Studio versions (2013 and 2015).

I think, I will contact Qt directly.